# How to do a blinking animation similar to this?

Tags: animation, uv, keyframes, uv-image-editor, animation-nodes

So I want to create a blinking animation like this and it looks as if instead of making the eye a mesh its a texture where he has 3-4 seperate images that he probaby keyframes to make the character blink. Is there a way to keyframe materials?

[image]

[image]

[image]

So how would I go about doing it? Just keyframe the materials??